# Writting matrix recursion with correct return?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion

This code prints all the subsets of a given set of numbers stored in an array input, using recursion. The subset are stored in a 2D matrix called output. The input is given directly by the interface, so I don't have to do anything.

The first column has the size of the numbers in the row. For ex, if row 3 has 2 elements, the first index of row 3 will have 2 stored in it. If there are no elements, put 0.

In the end, I have to return `ans`, which is the number of the rows present in the 2d matrix, containing the valid output.

```
int subset(int input[], int n, int A[][20]) {
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    int ans=subset(input+1,n-1,A[][20]);        //recursive call    
    for(int i=0;i<ans;i++){                     
            int x=A[i][0];
            for(int j=0;j<x;j++){
        A[i+ans][j]=A[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=ans;i<ans*2;i++){
        int x=A[i][0];
            for(int j=x;j>0;j--){
                A[i][j+1]=A[i][j];
            }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<ans*2;i++){
        A[i][0]++;

    }
    for(int i=ans;i<ans*2;i++)
        A[i][1]=input[0];

    return ans*2;
}
```

Comment: You should tag this question with the language that your code is written in

Comment: Show us an example of the input and output you are using. Also, tell us the language you are using.

Comment: Also, the title isn't very helpful. This could apply to pretty much any question.